# Prisma gave "Invalid `this.prisma.hotel.upsert()` invocation in"

Tags: orm, nestjs, prisma

I'm developing a NestJS application using Prisma. I wrote a service that take a CreateHotelDTO to find a hotel and create one if the hotel didn't exist with upsert. After many tries to modify schema and query, I still couldn't make it to work successfully (got the error in the title). What have I done wrong?
My schema:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
model Hotel{
    id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
    hotelCode String @unique
    rooms Room[]
  }
model Room{
    id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
    roomName String @unique
    status RoomStatus @default(BOOKED)
    hotel Hotel @relation(fields: [hotelCode], references: [hotelCode])
    hotelCode String @unique
  }
enum RoomStatus { 
  BOOKED 
  CHECKIN 
  CHECKOUT
}
```

My service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PrismaService } from 'src/orm/prisma.service';
import { CreateHotelDTO } from './dtos/create-hotel.dto';

@Injectable()
export class HotelsService {
  constructor(private prisma: PrismaService) {}

  async createHotel(createHotelDTO: CreateHotelDTO): Promise<any> {
    const hotel = await this.prisma.hotel.upsert({
      where: { hotelCode: createHotelDTO.hotelCode },
      update: {},
      create: {
        hotelCode: createHotelDTO.hotelCode,
        rooms: {
          createMany: {
            data: createHotelDTO.rooms,
          },
        },
      },
    });
    return hotel;
  }
}
```

My request body using postman:

```
{
    "hotelCode": "CITY",
    "rooms": [
        {
            "roomName":"201",
            "status": "BOOKED"
        },
        {
            "roomName":"202",
            "status": "BOOKED"
        },
        {
            "roomName":"203",
            "status": "BOOKED"
        }
    ]
}
```

The full error log:

```
Invalid `this.prisma.hotel.upsert()` invocation in
src\features\hotels\hotels.service.ts:10:43

   7 constructor(private prisma: PrismaService) {}
   8 
   9 async createHotel(createHotelDTO: CreateHotelDTO): Promise<any> {
→ 10   const hotel = await this.prisma.hotel.upsert(
Unique constraint failed on the constraint: `Room_hotelCode_key`
PrismaClientKnownRequestError:
Invalid `this.prisma.hotel.upsert()` invocation in
src\features\hotels\hotels.service.ts:10:43

   7 constructor(private prisma: PrismaService) {}
   8
   9 async createHotel(createHotelDTO: CreateHotelDTO): Promise<any> {
→ 10   const hotel = await this.prisma.hotel.upsert(
Unique constraint failed on the constraint: `Room_hotelCode_key`
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was I messed up with `prisma db push` and `prisma migrate dev`. Here's what happened:

1. I first create a database with hotelCode column in Room table set to @unique with `prisma migrate dev`.
2. Then I removed the @unique from hotelCode column from Row table in the schema file and apply change with `prisma db push`. Nothing changed inside of the database. This is where the problem arised.

The solution is removing all the migrate history and run `prisma db push` again. Everything works perfectly